# Variance of Itô integral on general time interval

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

I have a question concerning the variance of the Itô integral on general time intervals, i.e. I want to calculate
\begin{align*}\operatorname{Var}\left(\int_s^T f(t)dW_t\right),\end{align*}
where $f: [0, T]\to \mathbb{R}$ is deterministic, $W_t$ is the standard Wiener-process and $0<s<T$. For $s=0$ it is a standard fact that this equals $\int_0^Tf(t)^2dt$. I suspect that this should also hold for $s>0$ as it is true for step processes. Is this true or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $s\in[0,T)$, the variance in question is
$$\int_s^T f(t)^2\,dt.$$
This is shown just as in the case $s=0$.

Alternatively, the case $s\in(0,T)$ can be reduced to the case $s=0$ by noting that

- the random function $[0,T-s]\ni u\mapsto W^s_u:=W_{s+u}-W_s$ is a standard Wiener process on the interval $[0,T-s]$;
- $\int_s^T f(t)\,dW_t=\int_0^{T-s} f(s+u)\,dW^s_u$;
- the variance of $\int_0^{T-s} f(s+u)\,dW^s_u$ is $\int_0^{T-s} f(s+u)^2\,du=\int_s^T f(t)^2\,dt$.

Comment: There are three steps to your alternative argument, and (though it is clear in retrospect) I had trouble parsing where one ended and the next began.  Would you be willing to consider a comma in place of the first "and" (or perhaps even a list) to make it easier to parse?

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. Does it look better now?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456986/variance-of-it%c3%b4-integral-on-general-time-interval/456992#comment1183615_456992), much, thanks!